# Replace element from a list of values in a dictionnary by values from other dictionnary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm reeally sorry, being a noob in python is quite hard when you have project to do... Here is my problem

```
d= { 'a': [ '"123728"', '"102359"', '"110663"', '"110664"','"110665"', '"110666"', '"110667"', '"110668"', '"110669"', '"110670"', '"110671"', '"110672"', '"115663"', '"115664"', '"115665"', '"122330"', '"122351"', '"110673"', '"120433"', '"121831"'], 

    'b': ['"100016"', '"101424"', '"101948"', '"102832"', '"108834"', '"110397"', '"110622"', '"110679"', '"110680"', '"110681"', '"110682"', '"116693"', '"123331"', '"102359"', '"110683"', '"115666"', '"115667"', '"124098"', '"125243"', '"140965"', '"121002"']}
```

The value from the dict d are the keys from d1

```
d1= {'"110674"': '"Apple"', '"110682"': "Banana", '"123331"': "Melon", '"110397"': "Orange"} # correspondance
```

What I want is to replace the value from d to it correspondance in d1 and delete the one that do not correspond

```
d3= { 'a': "", 'b': ["Banana", "Melon", "Orange"]}
```

Here is my code

```
for key, value in d.items():
   for key2, value2 in d1.items():
      for elem in value:
         print(key2)
         if elem == key2:
            full_dict[key] = value2
pprint.pprint(full_dict)
```

But I have this result

```
defaultdict(None, {'b': 'Orange'})
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate `d` dictionary, then for each keys, iterate the dictionary `d1` and check if the key of the second dictionary exists in the value of the first dictionary, then add it to the result dictionary at last.

```py
result = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    temp = []
    for key,val in d1.items():
        if key in v:
            temp.append(val)
    result[k] = temp if temp else ''
    
result
{'a': '', 'b': ['Banana', 'Melon', 'Orange']}
```

**PS:** The expected output you have doesn't match for the given data, `Apple` should not have been there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following [dict comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
d3 = { key : [d1[v] for v in value if v in d1] for key, value in d.items() }
print(d3)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': [], 'b': ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Melon']}
```

The above is equivalent to the below for-loop:

```
d3 = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    d3[key] = [d1[v] for v in value if v in d1]
```

If you want to match the exact output (i.e an empty string in place of an empty list), use:

```
d3 = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    res = [d1[v] for v in value if v in d1]
    d3[key] = res if res else ""
print(d3)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': '', 'b': ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Melon']}
```

For a general introduction to looping techniques in Python, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).